# How to find most relevant dimensions/ columns to separate known classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have data acquired from thousands of cancer cells. 60 measurements per cell stored in a pandas dataframe. The cells are classified into 3 populations using another method.

I would like to know which of the parameters/dimensions most distinguish/separate the classes from one another.
I'm new to this and there are many options. I did try PCA decomposition from sklearn, but that just returned the 2-3 principles components of variation of the dataset not in relation to the classes (I still didn't find a way to print out the labels of the dimensions with the contributing most to this variation, help with that would be appreciated!)

So what's the best way to find the dimensions that change the most with each class. I was imagining a 2 parameter PCA with my classes separated as best it can.

Is it also possible to do the same thing to find the dimensions that change the most in regards to another dimension (column)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You want to use Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) instead of PCA.

PCA only finds components which represent the **complete** data set of all classes in an optimal way. In contrast to this, you want to find those components which help you to distinguish best **between the different classes**, which is what LDA is for.

Have a look at this example:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html

If you have trouble adapting this for you data, feel free to provide sample data and some LDA code and let us know where you are stuck.

[EDIT: sample code is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html  ]

Comment: Reviewing your answer I had to go brush up on some things, I found these slides to be really helpful as far as getting my head around the concepts, in particular it's not being pca.

https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/LDA-Primer-[Gutierrez-Osuna].pdf

Comment: Great stuff thanks! I have a pretty plot, but I'm struggling to get a ranking of the dimensions for discriminating against the classes. I had the same problem with the PCA. I suspect I'm not understanding something!

Comment: @ed3203 I think it would me most helpful for more detailed discussion if you could provide some data (maybe cut down to few dimensions) together with code.

Comment: @tfv The dataset is of the same format as the seaborn iris `iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")`
Using that as an example what would be the best way to determine the measurement parameters of the species that best separate the classes (ie highest probability of correctly assigning class on that measurement)
I still don't understand how to get the dimension ranking from LDA or PCA like i seem to have from random forest.
Ie for iris looking at a sns.pairplot it looks like petal length and width separate the classes the most.

Comment: Have you seen that sample code for iris and LDA? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html  The dimension will always be an INPUT for your LDA, you have to tell how many dimensions you want. You can loop over different dimension numbers and decide which to choose from the accuracy you get.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are on teh same page here: LDA gives you a new coordinate system, which means that one coordinate is no longer one single olfd featur, but a linear combination ("superposition") of many old features. If you want to reduce the number of original old features you have to determine, you need to do feature selection as in Random Forest

Answer (score 5):

You can determine feature importances via Random Forest as well. Rather than finding components that best distinguish between classes, this will tell you relative importance of your original features (which sounds like what you were asking for). Here's a link:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! So if I didn't know the classes before hand on a data set would it be reasonable to do a PCA, then on 2 pc perform k-mean or GMM. Then do a random forest on the determined classes to find the dimensions which contribute most to determine this class. 
Using the iris dataset  as an example in which don't know the classes beforehand. Would the above method be suitable to determine that there are 3 separate plant species?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to use PCA before kmeans. As tfv points out in his answer, PCA maintains commonalities in your data, but doesn't help distinguish between different classes. This means that PCA can cause you to lose important information necessary to separate, and thus, identify distinct clusters in your data. Are there certain scenarios where it could be helpful? Probably, but in general you shouldn't just blindly use PCA.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add the above discussion, it is important to understand the difference between the following two points:

- **Feature Selection in very high-dimensional datasets:** [Feture Selection in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). Using Random forest is another way of feature selection based on feature importances.
- **Dimensionality Reduction**: This is a technique where dataset is transformed into a new feature space of lower dimensionality than the original one. [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), [LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html) and [kernel PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html) are such techniques. PCA is unsupervised technique whereas LDA is supervised technique. PCA and LDA works well if dataset is linearly separable. If dataset is not linearly separable, then kernel PCA can be used to transform the data to new lower dimensional subspace that is suitable for linear classifier.