# Find the most relevant columns for each single class in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The following question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055978/how-to-find-most-relevant-dimensions-columns-to-separate-known-classes)) did not help me.

I have a big dataset, and I want to know which Columns are the most relevant for the Target Variable. I know that, in my case, for each class in the Target Variable, different Columns have a different impact.

In that question, the suggested answer recomend using LDA. From what I understood, it looks like a normal classification algorithm, so it's not what I need

What I what is something like

```
In : 
    magic_function("name_of_target_variable_1")
Out :
    ["really_important_column_a", "really_important_column_b" ...]
In : 
    magic_function("name_of_target_variable_2")
Out :
    ["really_important_column_a", "really_important_column_f" ...]
```

How can I obtain this result? Is there a way, in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could train a [RandomForest classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) for each of your target variables ([RandomForest regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) if the target variable is numeric).

Then you can check the [importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_) of each feature in predicting the target variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, in the first place?

What the OP wants to do (Features selection) is actually an incredible long topic, where there is not an official proper answer but there are many different possible approaches.

So, yes, it can be done, and no, there is not an official way to do it. There are many "just try this and check the results". This is not the kind of question for StackOverflow